# How to turn else if statements into single Excel nested statement

Tags: sql, excel, if-statement

I am trying to create a single Excel IF function that incorporates the below IF statements:

```
If Date_Time_of_Request <= Authorization_Start_Date then REVIEW_TYPE = 'Prospective';
Else If Authorization_Start_Date <= Date_Time_of_Request <= Discharge_Date then REVIEW_TYPE = 'Concurrent';
Else If Date_Time_of_Request > = Discharge_Date then REVIEW_TYPE = 'Retrospective';
Else If Date_Time_of_Request > = Authorization_End_Date then REVIEW_TYPE = 'Retrospective';
```

My attempt at this is: `=IF(AS2 <= J2, "PROSPECTIVE", IF(AND(AS2 >= J2,AS2 <= V2),"CONCURRENT",IF(OR(AS2 > V2,AS2 > H2),"RETROSPECTIVE","UNKNOWN")))`

However, V2 is blank in most rows, and I need it to move onto the next statement if V2 is blank. As it is currently written, AS2 > V2 being true most of the time (even with it being blank).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
and(AS2>V2,LEN(V2)>0)
```